# Spring roo and Google App engine one to many unowned bidirectional relationships

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm starting my way with Spring Roo 1.1 STS, GWT and GAE, and I was wondering what is the way to create unowned **bidirectional** one to many relations in Roo?

The expenses-gae.roo sample gives a starting point, but I see that the relations are unidirectional, e.g. from the many side to the one (expenses to report) but I would like to traverse the expenses from the report (e.g. have roo put the `mappedBy` annotation)

Seems like I'm missing something basic...

Related to this question (just added the "roo" aspect to it)

[Difference between owned one to many relationship and owned one to many bidirectional relationship(Google App Engine Java Api)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981298/difference-between-owned-one-to-many-relationship-and-owned-one-to-many-bidirecti)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last I checked ROO did not support one to many relationships for google app engine. Your commands would work in ROO but the code won't compile.
Also ROO is appengine agnostic and does not create optimized code specifically for appengine.

Use ROO to create the base and then build the app on your own.

Comment: Roo 1.1 has built in Google App Engine and GWT support